# How to incorporate two TextView with a CheckBox?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, checkbox, textview

I want to ask if how am I going to incorporate my two TextView with a Checkbox. The scenario is when I put values on my two EditText those value will be shown on two TextView respectively but I want the Checkbox be added automatically whenever I hit save. I hope that you get my question. Here are my codes:

**Adapter**

```
public String getData(String columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ITEMID, KEY_ITEM, KEY_QTY};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String resultQty = "";

    int iQty = c.getColumnIndex(columnIndex);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            resultQty = resultQty + c.getString(iQty) + "\n";
        }

    return resultQty;
}
```

**My onCreate method**

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
        Grocery info = new Grocery(this);
        info.open();
        String data = info.getData(KEY_ITEM);
        info.close();
        tv.setText(data);

        TextView tvQty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvItemQty);
        Grocery infoQty = new Grocery(this);
        infoQty.open();
        String dataQty = infoQty.getData(KEY_QTY);
        infoQty.close();
        tvQty.setText(dataQty);

        CheckBox android = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkStat);
        android.setChecked(false);
        onClick(tvQty);
```

**My XML code**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tvSQLinfo"
            android:id="@+id/tvSQLinfo"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="itemQty"
            android:id="@+id/tvItemQty"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/chkStat"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can add `android:visibility ="gone" or "invisible"` to your XML then set it to visible in your onClick() 'nameOfCheckbox.setVisibility(Checkbox.VISIBLE)'